# How can I build a regex to match a value?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, string

I need a regex that matches this kind of strings:

```
brand-new-car
brand-new-car-1
brand-new-car-100
307
```

and I just need to catch the "name" regardless of whether the string has `-count`; like this:

```
brand-new-car
brand-new-car
brand-new-car
307
```

This regex does not work properly. Its `$1` is the full string, not without `-count`.

```
(\S+)(?:-\d+|)$
```

Comment: Take a look at [Rubular: a Ruby regular expression editor](http://www.rubular.com/). It's very convenient for these sort of things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the first capture group "lazy" or non-greedy.

```
var re = new RegExp("^(\\S+?)(?:-\\d+)?$");

var testStrings = [
    "brand-new-car",
    "brand-new-car-1",
    "brand-new-car-100",
    "307"
];

for (var i=0; i<testStrings.length; i++) {
    var result = re.exec(testStrings[i]);
    say("result: " + result);
}
```

The results:

```
result: brand-new-car,brand-new-car
result: brand-new-car-1,brand-new-car
result: brand-new-car-100,brand-new-car
result: 307,307
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (?xms)(^[\w-]+.*?)(?=[\w-]+|\Z)
Here, below is an image of regex buddy [image]

where you can catch the "name" regardless of whether the string has -count the yellow and blue foreground highlights the different selections.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the pipe '|', then it works

```
(\S+)(?:-\d+)$
```

Checked here [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Yeah, my fault, didn't check another options